# Homogeneous Linear Differential Equation with Constant Coefficientes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation

$$x^{(n)} + c_{n-1} x^{(n-1)} + \dots + c_1 x' + c_0 = 0,$$

with $c_0, c_1, \dots, c_{n-1} \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $x(t) = t^ke^{\beta t}$ is a solution if and only if $\beta$ is a root of $z^n + c_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \dots + c_1z + c_0 = 0$ with multiplicity greater than $k$.

**Attempt:** I tried to solve this exercise in several ways, but they all led me to calculate $$(t^k e^{\beta t})^{(n)} + c_{n-1} (t^ke^{\beta t})^{(n-1)} + \dots + c_1 (t^ke^{\beta t})' + c_0.$$

After a few tries, I got that

$$(t^k e^{\beta t})^{(i)} = \sum_{j=0}^{i} i! \left( \begin{array}{c} k \\ k-j \end{array} \right) t^{k-j} \beta^{i-j} e^{\beta t}. $$

My initial idea was to use induction over $n$. The case $n = 1$ is quite easy, but it is too tedious to work with this sum through the rest of the induction. My professor suggested that I use Jordan Canonical Form, but I am having a hard time to understand how to use it in order to prove the equivalence.

Any help would be appreciated!